# jsTree leaf drag and drop with auto creation of its parent hierarchy

Tags: copy, move, jstree, drag-and-drop

I have two jstree , left and right.
From start I have 3 level tree in left tree, and I can drag and drop level 1 or level 2 at right side, but dont allow to drop leaf on right side.

Now I want some of leaf nodes of 3 level tree to be moved back to left tree ( however as now there is no tree hierarchy in left side) , either I would need to drop leaf back to left tree and auto create its parent information OR while first drag and drop from left tree to right tree, I would need to copy tree hierarchy but leaf to be MOVED only and not copy so that I will always have correct placeholder to drop item back to its original parent hierarchy

any help is appreciated.